# Cassandra upgrade from 2.2.1 to 3.0.0 fails with NullPointerException

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, cassandra-3.0

I tried upgrading Cassandra from 2.2.1 to 3.0.0 but Cassandra doesn't start:

```
ERROR [main] 2015-11-30 15:44:50,164 CassandraDaemon.java:702 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.delete(FileUtils.java:374) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.migrateDataDirs(SystemKeyspace.java:1341) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:180) [apache-cassandra-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:561) [apache-cassandra-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:689) [apache-cassandra-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
```

Anyone else faces this problem?
I also raised an issue here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10788

Here is TRACE level logging:

```
TRACE [MemtablePostFlush:1] 2015-12-01 16:47:52,675 ColumnFamilyStore.java:868 - forceFlush requested but everything is clean in schema_columns
TRACE [main] 2015-12-01 16:47:52,675 ColumnFamilyStore.java:1563 - Snapshot for Keyspace(name='system') keyspace data file /data/system/schema_columns-296e9c049bec3085827dc17d3df2122a/la-46-big-Data.db created in /data/system/schema_columns-296e9c049bec3085827dc17d3df2122a/snapshots/1448984872341-upgrade-2.2.1-3.0.0
TRACE [main] 2015-12-01 16:47:52,676 ColumnFamilyStore.java:1563 - Snapshot for Keyspace(name='system') keyspace data file /data/system/schema_columns-296e9c049bec3085827dc17d3df2122a/la-45-big-Data.db created in /data/system/schema_columns-296e9c049bec3085827dc17d3df2122a/snapshots/1448984872341-upgrade-2.2.1-3.0.0
TRACE [main] 2015-12-01 16:47:52,676 ColumnFamilyStore.java:1563 - Snapshot for Keyspace(name='system') keyspace data file /data/system/schema_columns-296e9c049bec3085827dc17d3df2122a/la-47-big-Data.db created in /data/system/schema_columns-296e9c049bec3085827dc17d3df2122a/snapshots/1448984872341-upgrade-2.2.1-3.0.0
TRACE [main] 2015-12-01 16:47:52,676 SystemKeyspace.java:1327 - Checking directory /data for old files
ERROR [main] 2015-12-01 16:47:52,751 CassandraDaemon.java:702 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.delete(FileUtils.java:374) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.migrateDataDirs(SystemKeyspace.java:1341) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:180) [apache-cassandra-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:561) [apache-cassandra-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:689) [apache-cassandra-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
```

It looks like the code is expected legacy files under /data directory but it can't find any and call FileUtils.delete(null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using this patch:
https://github.com/stef1927/cassandra/commit/1c464adf097d323320ce11db6daf05e1a31c62b6

More details:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10788

And thanks, I'll see if upgrading from 2.2.1 to 2.2.2 first helps.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that may impact your migration is the 2.1.x to 3.0 conversion is [not recommended](http://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeC_c.html) by Datastax.

> Cassandra 3.0.x restrictions
>
> Upgrade from Cassandra 2.1 versions greater or equal to 2.1.9 or from
>   Cassandra 2.2 versions ***greater or equal to 2.2.2***.
>
> *Emphasis added

The null pointer could be happening due to non-existent files or a duplicated delete call.

I would try upgrading to at least 2.2.2 before the 3.0 migration.